# Download web page using Java after javascript executes

Tags: java, file, download

I have a problem that doesn't seem to be answered clearly in StackOverflow. I want to download a page using Java and retrieve some data from it in order to give some values to an application that I develop. This page is a betting site so it contains javascrit methods to change the betting values.

In order to do some tests I downloaded the page manually using `Ctrl-S` and then I made a programm (with `FileReader, BufferedReader`, etc...) which retrieves the data. This worked perfectly. So I would make a bash script to be executed in order to download the page every time when the user opens my application.

After that I searched for methods who download the page programmatically (I used `Jsoup, URL`, ...). What I noticed is that the javascript variable values couldn't be printed because the javascript code wasn't executed.

What i want to know is that if there is some way to download programmatically the executed website (download the instance of the javascript values) without having to make some bash script to do it every time before someone opens my app.

Answer (score 0):

Try [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/). It is used for automatic testing but should fit your purpose well too!

Comment: I forgot to mention that I tried HTMLUnit as well. HTMLUnit seems to have some problems by parsing javascript as it returns runtime Errors..